# Clearing a Response in Postback to download text file from Button Click

Tags: asp.net, download, httpresponse, response.write

Now... I could do this is a separate page, but i don't want to!

I am trying to create a service which fetches a load of JS files required for a project, compresses them and downloads a single file, but what it does isn't really the issue, the downloading bit is not behaving as expected.

From many examples on here, including:
[In ASP.NET, how to get the browser to download string content into a file? (C#)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/898145/in-asp-net-how-to-get-the-browser-to-download-string-content-into-a-file-c)

I have the (simplified) code:

```
Sub Download() Handles button.click
    var AllTheScript as string ="blah blah blah"
    Response.Buffer = True
    Response.Clear()
    Response.ClearContent()
    Response.Write(AllTheScript)
    Response.ContentType = "application/text"
    Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=myJavascript.js")
    Response.Flush()
End Sub
```

Obviously, I also have an `<asp:button id="button" runat="server"/>` element in my page.

When I click this button, it does all the fetch work (not illustrated above) creates the text file and downloads it... excellent...

Except, at the bottom of the JS file it downloads `myJavascript.js` it has all the markup from the page in which the button was.

I was under the impression that `Response.ClearContent()` should remove all this?

What am I doing wrong? Or does this have to be a separate page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case anyone else comes across this issue again, I solved the problem, very simple!

All it needed was

```
Response.End()
```

At the end!

So the full function becomes:

```
Sub Download() Handles button.click
    var AllTheScript as string ="blah blah blah"
    Response.Buffer = True
    Response.Clear()
    Response.ClearContent()
    Response.Write(AllTheScript)
    Response.ContentType = "application/text"
    Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=myJavascript.js")
    Response.Flush()
    Response.End() '///<<< Final Line Essential!
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var context = HttpContext.Current;
```

context.Response.Clear();

context.Response.ClearHeaders();

context.Response.ClearContent();
////

context.Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=myJavascript.js");

content.Response.Write(AllTheScript);

Comment: Same result I am afraid :-(